# Modify Spring's RedisCacheConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis, spring-cache

I'm setting the configuration of a Spring Data Redis Cache on *application.properties* using the *spring.cache.redis.** keys.

However, not everything is possible to be configured on *application.properties* and I'd like to get a reference to the *RedisCacheConfiguration* created by Spring and do some further configuration on it.

From all the examples I found, it seems that this is not possible, since all of them show something like:

```
@Bean
RedisCacheConfiguration getRedisCacheConfiguration() {
    return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
           .serializeKeysWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(RedisSerializer.string()))
           .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(RedisSerializer.json()));
}
```

And the defaultCacheConfig method just ignores *application.properties*.

I also tried to get an *autowired* reference using:

```
@Bean
public RedisCacheManager getRedisCacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory, RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration) {
...
```

But that just results in an Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

So, is what I want to do impossible? Should I just forget about *application.properties* and configure everything in code?

I'm using Spring Boot (with spring-boot-starter-cache and spring-boot-starter-data-redis) 2.7.8, Java 17 and Lettuce 6.1.10.RELEASE.

Comment: please, provide the spring version and your redis dependencies versions. Are you using lettuce, jedis or another connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, I'm posting the solution I ended up with, but John Blum's answer offers more options.

```java
@Bean
public RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer redisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonObjectMapperBuilder) {
    var om = jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.createXmlMapper(false).build();
    var serializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(om.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, MyObject.class));
    serializer.setObjectMapper(om);
    
    return builder -> {
        builder.initialCacheNames(Set.of("mycache")); //remove this line if using spring.cache.cache-names on application.properties
        builder.getCacheConfigurationFor("mycache")
            .ifPresent(config -> builder.withCacheConfiguration("mycache", config
                .serializeKeysWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(RedisSerializer.string()))
                .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(serializer))));
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Out of curiosity, what aspect of (Redis) cache configuration are you trying to modify (or customize)?

Reviewing the [`RedisCacheConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/cache/RedisCacheConfiguration.html) class provided by *Spring Data Redis* (and used by *Spring Boot*), most of the configuration (allow `null` values, key prefix, statistics, TTL) are all configurable using *Spring Boot* [properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.cache). Of course, the properties do not cover non-scalar/primitive type configuration, such as the key/value Redis Serializer pairs or the `ConversionService` used.

First, have a [look at this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.caching.provider.redis) in the *Spring Boot* reference documentation.

Declaring a `RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer` bean in your application configuration enables you to set (and modify) the `RedisCacheConfiguration` for each `RedisCache` instance. This approach gives you complete control over individual cache configuration for each cache separately. See below.

Of course, if you declared many different caches for different purposes across your application, then this could be tedious. In addition, if you have predetermined caches declared with the `spring.cache.cache-names` *Spring Boot* property, which might vary by environment if you are using Spring Profiled `application.properties` files, then this could also be problematic.

On the other hand, even when using a large number of individual caches for different purposes, if they share common configuration then your job becomes much easier.

For shared, common cache configuration, you were on the right track by declaring a bean of type `RedisCacheConfiguration`. Bean name should not matter, though I might prefer "*redisCacheConfiguration*" rather than "*getRedisCacheConfiguration*". You can even inject the *Spring Boot* `CacheProperties` instance, which *Spring Boot* does register as a bean in the Spring `ApplicationContext`.

For example:

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
class MyCustomRedisCacheConfiguration {

  @Bean
  RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration(
      CacheProperties cacheProperties,
      ConversionService conversionService) {

    CacheProperties.Redis redisCacheProperties = cacheProperties.getRedis();

    SerializationPair<String> keySerializer = RedisSerializationContext
      .SerializationPair.fromSerializer(RedisSerializer.string())

    SerializationPair<?> valueSerializer = RedisSerializationContext
      .SerializationPair.fromSerializer(RedisSerializer.json())

    RedisCacheConfiuration redisCacheConfiguration = 
      RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
        .entryTtl(redisCacheProperties.getTimeToLive())
        .prefixCacheNameWith(redisCacheProperties.getKeyPrefix())
        .serializeKeysWith(keySerializer)
        .serializeValuesWith(valueSerialier)
        .withConversionService(conversionService);

    if (!redisCacheProperties.isCacheNullValues()) {
      redisCacheConfiguration.disableCachingNullValues();
    }

    if (!redisCacheProperties.isUseKeyPrefix()) {
      redisCacheConfiguration.disableKeyPrefix();
    }

    return redisCacheConfiguration;
  }
```

The (Redis) `CacheProperties` are the resolved properties from *Spring Boot* `application.properties` file(s), specific to caching (i.e. `spring.cache.*`).

This is not unlike what *Spring Boot's* *auto-configuration* already does (follow from [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.7.8/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/RedisCacheConfiguration.java#L61), then [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.7.8/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/RedisCacheConfiguration.java#L77) and finally, [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.7.8/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/RedisCacheConfiguration.java#L80-L100)) if you do not explicitly declare a bean of type `RedisCacheConfiguration`.

The [default `RedisCacheConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.7.8/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/RedisCacheConfiguration.java#L80-L100) provided by *Spring Boot* [is used](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.7.8/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/RedisCacheConfiguration.java#L77) if you did NOT explicitly declare a bean of type `RedisCacheConfiguration`.

> TIP: [`ObjectProvider.getIfAvailable(:Supplier<?>)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider.html#getIfAvailable(java.util.function.Supplier)) only invokes the `Supplier` if the `ObjectProvider` cannot provide an Object of the declared type. And, in this case, the `ObjectProvider` implementation would most likely be a `BeanObjectProvider` implementation used by Spring's `DefaultListableBeanFactory` delegated to by Spring's `ApplicationContext` to manage beans.

You will also notice that *Spring Boot* does not register the default, provided `RedisCacheConfiguration` as a bean in the Spring `ApplicationContext` anywhere in the *Spring Boot* [`RedisCacheConfiguration` class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.7.8/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/RedisCacheConfiguration.java) (used in *auto-configuration*), which is why you encountered a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` when you tried to inject what you thought was a bean when *Spring Boot* created the SD Redis `RedisCacheConfiguration` object (it doesn't).

Now, how to handle the individual Redis cache configuration when you need to deviate from the (default), shared `RedisCacheConfiguration` that might be applicable to most of your cache instances, but not all of them (perhaps)?

This is where the `RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer` can help!

Again, as the [documentation reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.caching.provider.redis) that I shared with you above describes, you must declare a bean of type `RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer` in your application configuration.

> TIP: You can see that *Spring Boot's* auto-configuration (for Redis) [applies this "customizer"](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.7.8/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/RedisCacheConfiguration.java#L69) to the `RedisCacheManager` bean that gets created in auto-config. There can even be more than one, which might be useful when you enable multiple Spring Profiles and there are different customizations applied based on environment and other factors (e.g. runtime, etc).

For example:

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
class MyCustomRedisCacheConfiguration {

  @Bean
  RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer redisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer() {

    return cacheManagerBuilder -> {

      cacheManagerBuilder
        .getCacheConfigurationFor("cacheRequiringIndividualCustomization")
        .ifPresent(redisCachConfiguration -> {
           
          RedisCacheConfiguation modifiedRedisCacheConfiguration = 
            redisCacheConfiguration.entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(5L))
              .prefixCacheNamesWith("customCacheNamePrefix");

          // maybe even with different, custom key/value Serializers

          cacheManagerBuilder
            .withCacheConfiguration("cacheRequiringIndividualCustomization",
              modifiedRedisCacheConfiguration);
        });
    };
  }
}
```

The `RedisCacheManagerBuilder` even allows you to [specify a default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/cache/RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.html#cacheDefaults(org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration)) `RedisCacheConfiguration` to use for all caches if you are not explicitly customizing all individual cache instances. The `cacheDefaults(:RedisCacheConfiguration`) method on `RedisCacheManagerBuilder` used to set defaults for all created cache instances alleviates the need for you to declare the custom `RedisCacheConfiguration` bean explicitly as I demonstrated first, above.

Alright, I will leave you with this.

Hopefully it gives you ideas and choices on how to best proceed in your particular case. Just know that Spring always has you covered. It might take a little digging, but I have yet to come across a situation that is not possible.

Good luck!

Comment: I apologize in advance if there are any typos in my answer or code examples as I typed both from memory and not an actual code example, :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm using the spring.cache.redis.cache-null-values, spring.cache.redis.enable-statistics and spring.cache.redis.time-to-live properties and setting the key and value serializers for each cache using the Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.

I'm also setting the ObjectMapper using Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I think what you posted below is just fine. If you need to retain the configuration from properties, just remember you can inject the `CacheProperties` object created by Boot into your `@Bean` method as well. Wishing you success.